# How can I add a variable to a jquery selector of a pseudo-class?

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

is it possible to add a variable to a jquery string selector of a pseudo-element? I've tried both codes below but none has seen to work, could you please assist me?

```
   $(function () {
    $("option").click(function(){
    var filt1 = $(this).attr('id');
 $("#filter2 option[class!=filt1]").hide();
  $("#filter2 option[id*=filt1]").show();
});
});
```

and

```
 $(function () {
        $("option").click(function(){
        var filt1 = $(this).attr('id');
     $('#filter2 option[class!='+ filt1+ ']').hide();
      $('#filter2 option[id*='+ filt1+']').show();
    });
    });
```

Comment: could you provide some HTML output too?

Comment: Events and hide on `<option>` are not supported in some browsers (IE & Safari for example). Use change event on `<select>` and either disable or remove options

Comment: I'm trying to create a variable so that I don't need to copy and paste the code for each and every id. Please check this jsfiddle:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vitordhers/zw0a9d4m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events and hide are not supported on `<option>` cross browser! Remove and append based on values in first select

First store and remove the `<option>`s in #filter2.

Change to using the value on options in filter1 and use the change event of the `<select>`.

Then when a change is made...clone and filter the stored `<option>` and put the filtered ones only into #filter2

```js
var $filter2 = $('#filter2'),
  // store options for #filter2
  $filter2Opts = $filter2.children().detach();

$('#filter1').change(function() {    
  var $newOpts = $filter2Opts.clone().filter('.' + $(this).val())
  $filter2.html($newOpts);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple size="2" id="filter1">
  <option value="opt1">I'm option 1</option>
  <option value="opt2"> I'm option 2</option>
</select>

<select multiple size="4" id="filter2">
  <option class="opt1"> I'm option 1 sub-option A</option>
  <option class="opt1"> I'm option 1 sub-option B</option>
  <option class="opt2"> I'm option 2 sub-option A</option>
  <option class="opt2"> I'm option 2 sub-option B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yep, that solves it very elegantly. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Your second try is close, you're just missing quotes around your attribute value:

```
$(function () {
   $("option").click(function(){
      var filt1 = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#filter2 option[class!="'+ filt1+ '"]').hide();
      $('#filter2 option[id*="'+ filt1+'"]').show();
   });
});
```

But if I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you may want this:

```
$(function () {
    $("option").click(function(){
        var filt1 = $(this).attr('id');     
        $('#filter2 option').hide();
        $('#filter2 option.'+ filt1).show();
    });
});
```

But as charlietfl said, hiding options via CSS isn't cross browser compatible, so you may want to do it the way they said.