# Troubleshooting Dependent List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a dropdown list where the scope number will be dependent on the cm name. I have tried and tried my code, and every time I run it, I can select a cm name, but then the scope number box will not allow me to pick any scope number. Any suggestions?

## HTML Code

```
<body>
  <form action="submitform.asp" method="post" name="tipinvestmentsemiannualprogressform " id="tipinvestmentsemiannualprogressform ">
    <h2>TIP Investment Semi-Annual Progress Form</h2>
    <table width="50% " border="0 " cellspacing="0 " cellpadding="5 ">
      <tr>
        <td width="41% " align="right " valign="middle ">CM Name :</td>
        <td width="59% " align="left " valign="middle ">
          <select name="cmname " id="cmname ">
        <option value=" ">Select CM Name</option>
        <option value="p_c ">P C</option>
        <option value="g_g ">G G</option>
        <option value="b_h ">B H</option>
        <option value="b_h ">S H</option>
        <option value="k_k ">K K</option>
        <option value="j_l ">J L</option>
        <option value="e_l ">E L</option>
        <option value="r_t ">R T</option>
        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right " valign="middle ">Scope Number :</td>
        <td align="left " valign="middle ">
          <select disabled="disabled " id="scopenumber " name="scopenumber ">
        <option class="label " value>Select Scope Number</option>
        <!-- P C -->
        <option rel="p_c " value="black ">black</option>
        <!-- G G-->
        <option rel="g_g " value="red ">red</option>
        <!-- B H -->
        <option rel="b_h " value="orange ">orange</option>
        <!-- S H -->
        <option rel="s_h " value="yellow ">yellow</option>
        <!-- K K -->
        <option rel="k_k " value="green ">green</option>
        <!-- J L -->
        <option rel="j_l " value="blue ">blue</option>
        <!-- E L -->
        <option rel="e_l " value="indigo ">indigo</option>
        <!-- R T -->
        <option rel="r_t " value="violet ">violet</option>
        </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
```

## JS

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function()) {

  var $cat = $("#cmname"),
    $subcat = $("#scopenumber");

  $cat.on("change", function()) {

    var _rel = $(this).val();

    $subcat.find("option").attr("style", "");
    $subcat.val("");

    if (!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled", true);

    $subcat.find("[rel=" + _rel + "]").show();
    $subcat.prop("disabled", false);
  });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: You can not hide `<option>` in some browsers...notably IE & Safari. Same for using events on `<option>`. Choices are remove/replace or disable

Comment: Typos all the way down. `$(function()) {` and `$cat.on("change", function()) {` both have extra trailing `(`s. Then, your `id`s have spaces at the end, so your lookups by `id` will fail. Your [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) should have complained about the first part, at least. Fixing the typos lets things start to work, as seen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEzJWy)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still didn't limit the selection of answers on scope number based on cm selection. @PaulRoub

Comment: That's why this wasn't an answer. Fixing typos and checking console errors is step 1. Others are at least trying to address the rest in the answers.

Comment: By removed/replaced/disabled does that mean that the scope number option would be lighter than the cm name box and would not allow you to select a color? @charlietfl

Comment: depends on the behavior you are wanting. See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/45046009/1175966

Comment: I don't have extensive experience with coding, and I'm not great with JavaScript. Do you mean what do I want the two drop down lists to do? @charlietfl

Comment: I think you want certain ones removed or disabled from `#scopenumber ` based on selections in `#cmname`  correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. @charlietfl

Answer (score -1):

i think you want to change this line :

```
$subcat.find("[rel=" + _rel + "]").show();
```

to:

```
$subcat.find("[rel=" + _rel + "]").prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with all the typos in the code preventing it from working and if this was the intent would be simpler to set `val()` on the select

Comment: that is true, but after all the typo's are fixed simply `show()` an `<option>` will not make the select's value become that

Comment: *"scope number box will not allow me to pick any scope"* ... not asking how to select an option

Comment: I don't understand your second comment @charlietfl